# Apache2 Worker Starting Tons of Processes

Tags: apache-2.2, memory

I am installed apache2-mpm-worker and left all config files default (I've never touched them much).

Is it normal that when I restart apache there is at least 20 apache processes starting? Shouldn't it be just 2 like it says in the configuration? Also, my memory seems to grow very quickly until my machine crashes.

I don't have any mods installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Thus is normal. There is a setting in `httpd.conf, which controls it. But yes, multiple apache processes are normal and even needed if you are getting any sort of traffic to your site. Obviously, if the traffic goes up, you may want to raise those settings.

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers         15
    MaxClients          450
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```